# Array change input like if A change to B for example

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation, input

Question: so i have a form with arrays that sends data to excel but i need the time that they put in the form to be `:` and not `.` is there a way i can check the array like

if `$time` = `00.00` change to `00:00` like that, can I do that ?

if not is there a way to lock the format of the input form so it only accepts `00:00` and if they put `00.00` they will get something that says its wrong ?

Edit:
i have a list but if they doesent use it

```
<input list="start" name="start[]" value="" class="listbox" /> 
<datalist id="start">
<option value="08:00"/> 
<option value="08:30"/> 
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an HTML5 `pattern` to confirm the input meets your requirements.

```
pattern="^\d+:\d+$"
```

This requires the field has numbers to start with, a colon, and then ends with numbers. You also should have a validation server side incase someone bypasses the check, or is using an older browser.

```
if(!preg_match('/^\d+:\d+$/', $_POST['field'])) {
      echo 'Invalid input';
}
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/xp8IzI/1

Another client side option would be using a `select` in place of the `datalist` and `input`, that won't allow them to enter altering times though.

```
<select name="start[]" class="listbox"> 
     <option value="08:00">08:00</option> 
     <option value="08:30">08:30</option> 
</select>
```